# React Native secure store not storing object properly after reload

Tags: react-native

I'm learning react native and I'm trying to figure out SecureStore. Why is it that when I logged in and successfully stored my user token in SecureStore, I can't use it again if I reload the screen using "RR". It does the same thing when I make changes to the code.

When I log the user object console.log(user), I see it, but I can't use it using the console.log(user.token). It comes up as undefined? IF I json.parse the user object, it works fine but I don't need to parse it when I initially logged in. What is the deal here and how can I keep using the object without parsing it first?

Here's the AuthProvider.js

LOG  [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 401]

```
login: (email, password) => {
                setIsLoading(true);
                axiosConfig.post('login', {
                    email,
                    password,
                    device_name: 'mobile'
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        const userResponse = {
                            token: response.data.token,
                            id: response.data.user.id,
                            name: response.data.user.name,
                            email: response.data.user.email,
                            avatar: response.data.user.avatar_url,
                        };

                        // communicate with backend and store token in secure store
                        setUser(userResponse);
                        setError(null);
                        SecureStore.setItemAsync('user', JSON.stringify(userResponse))
                        setIsLoading(false);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        // If the user haven't confirm the code. Show button to re-send the link
                        if(error.response.data.has_link){
                            setHasLink(true)
                        }
                        setError(error.response.data.message)
                        setIsLoading(false);
                });
            },
```

Here is the HomeStreen.jsx

```
        axiosConfig.defaults.headers.common[
            'Authorization'
            ] = `Bearer ${user.token}`;

        axiosConfig
            .get(`/my-animals?page=${page}`)
            .then(response => {
                // console.log(response.data);
                if (page === 1) {
                    setAnimals(response.data.data);
                } else {
                    setAnimals([...data, ...response.data.data]);
                }

                if (!response.data.next_page_url) {
                    setIsAtEndOfScrolling(true);
                }

                setIsLoading(false);
                setIsRefreshing(false);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                setIsLoading(false);
                setIsRefreshing(false);
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my own question. I added a condition to check the user object in the useEffect hook and then parsing the object before passing it into the axios.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(user){
        let userObj = JSON.parse(user);
        setUser(userObj);
    }
},[]);
```